# How to open Settings > More > Location Services > My Places programatically

Tags: android, location

I basically want to open this screen in my app:

[image]

I was hoping to something similar to this code below that is used to open Bluetooth Settings:

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
            "com.android.settings.bluetoothSettings");
    intent.setComponent(cn);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```